# Transforming JSON

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to transform JSON data provided by Quandl into a custom JSON format so that I can load it into my database.

The JSON Array is stock market data with Date, High, Low, Open, Close values. I need a flat JSON instead of an array.

I tried the following, but it returns full array instead of individual element. If I use [0][1], [0][2], it returns empty values.

Here is my [code](https://tonicdev.com/gvsrini/569df34446475a0d00e35a80)

```
var DataTransform = require("node-json-transform").DataTransform

var myData = {"dataset":{"data":[["2016-01-15",292.5,294.4,267.1,279.9,273.0,64104.0,182.09],["2016-01-14",288.0,302.0,265.0,287.6,288.2,68271.0,199.82],["2016-01-13",303.95,307.65,275.0,290.1,292.75,99921.0,293.08]]}}

var map = {
    list : 'dataset.data',
    item: {
        date: [0],
        high: [0][1],
        low: [0][0][1]
    }
};

var dataTransform = DataTransform(myData, map);
var result = dataTransform.transform();
console.log(result);
```

======================================================================

## Output

[{"date":[["2016-01-15",292.5,294.4,267.1,279.9,273,64104,182.09]],"high":"","low":""},{"date":[["2016-01-14",288,302,265,287.6,288.2,68271,199.82]],"high":"","low":""},{"date":[["2016-01-13",303.95,307.65,275,290.1,292.75,99921,293.08]],"high":"","low":""}]

Comment: OK and what would you ideally have ?

Comment: I want something like this:[{date:"2016-01-15",high:"294.4",low:"267.1"},...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the built-in *Array* functions for transforming data. e.g. *map, reduce, filter, sort*, etc. In this case *map* will do the job perfectly. e.g.

```
var ds = {"dataset":{"data":[["2016-01-15",292.5,294.4,267.1,279.9,273.0,64104.0,182.09],["2016-01-14",288.0,302.0,265.0,287.6,288.2,68271.0,199.82],["2016-01-13",303.95,307.65,275.0,290.1,292.75,99921.0,293.08]]}}

var transformed = ds.dataset.data
    .map(function (d) {
        return {
            date : d[0],
            high : d[1],
            low : d[2],
            etc:
        }
    })

// output in format : [{date:"2016-01-15",high:"294.4",low:"267.1"},...]
```